# Getting the text content of a parent View in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have something like this in React Native

```
<View>
   <Text>Hello</Text>
   <Text>World</Text>
</View>
```

which is created by mapping through text and wrapping each sentence or chunk of text in a View, and each word in a Text component.

Is there any way I can get all of the text content of the View component by pressing on any of the children? Like tapping "Hello" and getting "Hello World" loaded into state.

Comment: no, you can calculate "Hello World" from the data you are using to render those texts. Think of how you would get this "Hello World" without even rendering any text

Comment: You should read this resource https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html